# How use @Preview annotation of JetpackCompose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I was developing an App where I'm using Jetpack Compose as UI Design kit-tool, and as I'm quite begginer on this, I would like to know how make use of the @Preview annotation which allow to check your component visually.

I have this component:

```
@Composable
fun PokemonListScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: PokemonListViewModel = hiltNavGraphViewModel()
) {

    Surface(
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.background,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    )
    {
        Column {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_international_pok_mon_logo),
                contentDescription = "Pokemon",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .align(CenterHorizontally)
            )
            SearchBar(
                hint = "Search...",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(16.dp)
            ) {

                viewModel.searchPokemonList(it)

            }

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
            PokemonList(navController = navController)


        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun SearchBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    hint: String = " ",
    onSearch: (String) -> Unit = { }
) {

    var text by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    var isHintDisplayed by remember {
        mutableStateOf(hint != "")
    }

    Box(modifier = modifier) {
        BasicTextField(value = text,
            onValueChange = {
                text = it
                onSearch(it)
            },
            maxLines = 1,
            singleLine = true,
            textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.Black),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .shadow(5.dp, CircleShape)
                .background(Color.White, CircleShape)
                .padding(horizontal = 20.dp, vertical = 12.dp)
                .onFocusChanged {
                    // isHintDisplayed = it != FocusState.Active && text.isEmpty()
                }
        )
        if (isHintDisplayed) {
            Text(
                text = hint,
                color = Color.LightGray,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(horizontal = 20.dp, vertical = 12.dp)

            )
        }

    }
}

@Composable
fun PokemonList(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: PokemonListViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

    val pokemonList by remember { viewModel.pokemonList }
    val endReached by remember { viewModel.endReached }
    val loadError by remember { viewModel.loadError }
    val isLoading by remember { viewModel.isLoading }
    val isSearching by remember { viewModel.isSearching }


    LazyColumn(contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp)) {

        val itemCount = if (pokemonList.size % 2 == 0) {
            pokemonList.size / 2
        } else {
            pokemonList.size / 2 + 1
        }

        items(itemCount) {
            if (it >= itemCount - 1 && !endReached && !isLoading && !isSearching) {
                viewModel.loadPokemonPaginated()
            }
            PokedexRow(rowIndex = it, entries = pokemonList, navController = navController)
        }
    }


    Box(
        contentAlignment = Center,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        if (isLoading) {
            CircularProgressIndicator(color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
        }
        if (loadError.isNotEmpty()) {
            RetrySection(error = loadError) {
                viewModel.loadPokemonPaginated()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I try to do something like this:

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun previewPokemonListScreen(){
    PokemonListScreen(
        navController = rememberNavController(),
        viewModel = hiltNavGraphViewModel())
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
  Delete access not allowed during rendering (C:\Users\manuel.lucas\AndroidStudioProjects\JetpackComposePokedex\.gradle\build-attribution\androidGradlePluginAttributionData)
```

So how should I initialized my @Preview component. I have to pass some extra argument than the original componenent doesn't have.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What happens if you make `navController` and `viewModel` nullable and set them as null in preview?

Comment: It seems that viewmodel and navcontroller can't be used in preview. You need to set them as nullable like @PrimožIvančič said.

Comment: Make sure you're on a debug build or preview won't work

Comment: @Chris you make the trick ! Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Try to do like this

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun PreviewPokemonListScreen() {
   YourThemeAppName {
      PokemonListScreen(
         navController = rememberNavController(), //Remove the view model
      ) 
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! Still the same